# Invalid resource handle returned from cudaLaunchKernel when using non-default GPU

Tags: cuda

I have a CUDA program that runs without error when left to run on the default GPU.  When I set the device to GPU #1 in the very first line in my `main()` function, there is no immediate error (which is not a surprise, since `nvidia-smi` confirms that I have 8 GPUs in the machine).  Much later, when the program attempts to launch the kernel, an `invalid resouce handle(400)` error is encountered.

I've attempted to come up with a minimal viable example, but of course the below code runs fine.  Still, it illustrates the concept, so I include it.  **My real code uses multiple CPU threads, each launching their own kernel.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <cuda.h>


static void CheckCudaErrorAux (const char *, unsigned, const char *, cudaError_t);
#define CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(value) CheckCudaErrorAux(__FILE__,__LINE__, #value, value)

void CheckCudaErrorAux (const char *file, unsigned line, const char *statement, cudaError_t err) {
    if (err == cudaSuccess)
        return;
    std::cerr << statement<<" returned " << cudaGetErrorString(err) << "("<<err<< ") at "<<file<<":"<<line << std::endl;
    exit (1);
}


__global__ void foo() {
    printf("I'm a foo\n");
}

int main() {

    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaSetDevice(1));
    cudaStream_t stream;
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaStreamCreateWithFlags(&stream, cudaStreamNonBlocking));

    void *kernelArgs[] = {
    };

    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaLaunchKernel((void*) &foo, 80, 4, kernelArgs, 0, stream)); // THIS RETURNS THE INVALID RESOURCE HANDLE
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaStreamSynchronize(stream));

    printf("Finished kernel; exiting gracefully.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

My impression is that it's most likely an issue with the stream.  However, since the real program runs fine under the default GPU, without any change to the stream, I'm inclined to rule that out.

I'm very new to multi-gpu programming, and so I'm looking for advice on what else could cause this problem.  Thanks!

**Update**

Changing the kernel invocation to use the default stream instead of the specified stream produces no error.  But when I try to synchronize on the default stream, I ran into other issues (which might be solvable, but then we figured out the solution, so I stopped there).

Comment: why are you using `cudaLaunchKernel` (instead of launching kernels the way everyone else does)?  I'm suspicious of the heap allocation.  Is that 16GB?  Do you need that much?  Are all of your GPUs the same?  What kind are they/how much memory do they have?  Is this on windows or linux?

Comment: Thanks for the questions.  I'm actually using cudaLaunchCooperativeKernel to take advantage of the cooperative features, but I get the problem with both functions.  I use about 15GB of the 16 GB available on each GPU, allocated with `cudaMalloc(...)` calls.  I'll have a look into decreasing that size and see if it helps.  It's a carry-over from back when I used malloc() locally on the GPU a lot.  This is on Linux with 8 16GB V100s.

Comment: You almost certainly should not be using that line that way on a 16GB GPU.  1<<34 is 16GB.  That means you are reserving **all** the GPU memory for in-kernel allocations. At module load time, [the module load will fail](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#heap-memory-allocation), and I wouldn't be surprised if you get an invalid resource handle referring to a kernel that belonged to a module that failed to load.

Comment: Thanks for the idea -- "unfortunately" commenting out the heap reservation didn't change any of the behavior (the default gpu case works, and the non-default gpu case hits the same error).  I've updated the question to comment out that line.

Comment: maybe in your real code you have switched devices before you get to the kernel call.  maybe insert a call to cudaGetDevice() immediately prior to the cudaLaunchKernel to confirm which device it is being launched on (i.e. print it out).  A created stream applies to a particular device only.

Comment: bingo!  My presumption that the value set by cudaSetDevice(...) would be inherited by all spawned CPU threads was invalid.  Each spawned thread needs to call cudaSetDevice(...) itself.  It's convenient that each CPU thread can be associated with a different device -- just surprised me is all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each CPU thread can be associated with a different GPU device.

As such, once I modified the threads' execution so that they each called cudaSetDevice(1) after they were spawned, the problem went away.

The problem originally occurred because the streams were created for the 1st GPU device, but the spawned cpu threads were trying to launch the kernel on the default gpu (i.e., device 0).

This is roughly discussed in https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cuda-pro-tip-always-set-current-device-avoid-multithreading-bugs/

Comment: the spawned cpu threads were trying to launch the kernel on the default **GPU** (i.e. device 0)